# Using CSS to make my gradient image stretch itself vertically

Tags: css, layout

I need some help.

Here's what I'm getting right now:
[img ref](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUsQE.png)

I need the gradient to stretch itself vertically using CSS.

Here's the code for my CSS + HTML.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test Site 1 - Color Palettes and Scheme Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="TestSiteCSS.css" type="text/css">      
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="Content">
            <img src="Logo.png" alt="Logo MiCompra" />  

            <H1>Bienvenidos a MiCompra!</H1>
            <p>Bienvenidos a MiCompra. Compre lo que quiera, cuando quiera.</p>
            <p>Bienvenidos a MiCompra. Compre lo que quiera, cuando quiera.</p>
            <p>Bienvenidos a MiCompra. Compre lo que quiera, cuando quiera.</p>
            <p>Bienvenidos a MiCompra. Compre lo que quiera, cuando quiera.</p>
            <p>Bienvenidos a MiCompra. Compre lo que quiera, cuando quiera.</p>
            <p>Bienvenidos a MiCompra. Compre lo que quiera, cuando quiera.</p>
            <p>Bienvenidos a MiCompra. Compre lo que quiera, cuando quiera.</p>
            <p>Bienvenidos a MiCompra. Compre lo que quiera, cuando quiera.</p>
            <p>Bienvenidos a MiCompra. Compre lo que quiera, cuando quiera.</p>
            <p>Bienvenidos a MiCompra. Compre lo que quiera, cuando quiera.</p>
            <p>Bienvenidos a MiCompra. Compre lo que quiera, cuando quiera.</p>
            <p>Bienvenidos a MiCompra. Compre lo que quiera, cuando quiera.</p>
            <p>Bienvenidos a MiCompra. Compre lo que quiera, cuando quiera.</p>
            <p>Bienvenidos a MiCompra. Compre lo que quiera, cuando quiera.</p>
            <p>Bienvenidos a MiCompra. Compre lo que quiera, cuando quiera.</p>
            <p>Bienvenidos a MiCompra. Compre lo que quiera, cuando quiera.</p>
            <p>Bienvenidos a MiCompra. Compre lo que quiera, cuando quiera.</p>                     
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

/*Separete CSS file*/

```
body 
{
    background-image: url("TestPatternClouds.png");  
    background-repeat: repeat;
    margin: auto;
    width: 780px; /* or other value */
}

.Content
{
    margin: auto;
    width: 780px; /* or other value */
    /*background-color: #4AD0EB;*/
    background-image: url("TestContentBackground.png");
    back
}
```

Comment: Why don't ask this in doctype (http://doctype.com/)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't stretch it. What you can do, though, is change its `background-repeat` to `repeat-x` and set a background colour equal to the color of the bottom of the image. This'll display the gradient only once vertically, then display a solid colour with no seam between the two

Comment: 2 years on and this answer still helped me out!

Comment: seems to be the best solution until gradients are widely supported in CSS.

Comment: I forgot to force the repeat to repeat-x only. Works perfect now!

Answer (score 1):

The [CSS3 `background-size` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-size) will allow you to specify a percentage for a background image's height, but until it's widely supported there's no way to do this directly.

ceejayoz's suggestion is probably your best bet; and if you use a really tall gradient the effect won't be all that noticeable (I've used the same technique on several pages I've designed).

Comment: Works today, at least on Chrome and Firefox :)

Answer (score 1):

In the near future, you can use CSS gradients to do that. This already works in [**Safari 4**](http://webkit.org/blog/175/introducing-css-gradients/), and will also work in [**Firefox 3.6**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Gradients). The whole thing is still rather experimental, though, and the details will likely change as CSS3 evolves.

For **Opera** you could use SVG. Create a file like this (example taken largely from the [SVG specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/pservers.html#LinearGradients)):

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <g>
    <defs>
      <linearGradient id="MyGradient" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="100%">
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="blue" />
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="white" />
      </linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <rect fill="url(#MyGradient)" width="100%" height="100%"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

And then simply use that as the background image:

```
.Content { background: url(gradient.svg); }
```

For **Internet Explorer** you could use a [gradient filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532997(VS.85).aspx). E.g.

```
.Content {
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(
        startColorstr='blue', endColorstr='white', gradientType='0');
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(
        startColorstr='blue', endColorstr='white', gradientType='0')";
}
```

Other than this, and for browsers that don't support any of these, your best bet is to follow the suggestion given by [ceejayoz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367925/using-css-to-make-my-gradient-image-stretch-itself-vertically/1367952#1367952), [Thinker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367925/using-css-to-make-my-gradient-image-stretch-itself-vertically/1367948#1367948) and [Donut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367925/using-css-to-make-my-gradient-image-stretch-itself-vertically/1367959#1367959) before me: don't (vertically) repeat the gradient image and set the background to that of the end of the gradient.

Answer (score 0):

You probably can't. Is it an option to produce a taller gradient image, that will not always be entirely shown (you won't always see all the way to white) but will always be tall enough? It's not too hard to hide the overflow...

Answer (score 0):

You cant stretch it, when image is set as a background.

Things you can do:

1. Ugly way: use IMG tag and stretch it height.
2. Good way: set background to white url(...) no-repeat, so all after gradient would be in color of last line of your gradient.

Answer (score 0):

You can't stretch images using CSS